# "\S+?@\S+" and "\S+@\S+" give same output in regular expressions

Tags: regex

The following two regularexpressions give the same output in python 3.7.
"+?" is supposed to be non-greedy

```
re.findall("\S+?@\S+?","From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008")
re.findall("\S+@\S+","From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008")
```

Both of these give the same output as:

```
 ['stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za']
```

Answer (score 0):

The +? is non-greedy as expected. Refer https://regex101.com/r/DM4voj/1

If you copy pasted both the commands into your shell or program, you will only get the output of the last command.  Try using print statements for both. You should get the desired answers.

```
import re
print(re.findall("\S+?@\S+?","From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008"))
print(re.findall("\S+@\S+","From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008"))
```

The result will be as below as expected

```
['stephen.marquard@u']  
['stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za']
```